# 'Find my Friends' HTTP service returns VMP4 files instead of JPEG

Tags: ios, http, dictionary

I intercept HTTP traffic to/from 'Find my Friends' iOS application. 
The HTTP GET request for actual map received the response which shows it's body should include 'image/jpeg' but the actual data starts with "VMP4".

Where can I find any info about this VMP4 format?
Thanks

Comment: Don't quote me on this but aren't iOS Map Tiles vectors where the old pre-ios6 tiles use to be images? I've never heard of a vmp4 but the v could stand for vector?

Comment: Where can I find any info about those tiles? Some kind of vectorized graphics?